# How do you speed up image loads?

Tags: css, html, performance, jpeg

I'm a newbie developer. Built this site with Bootstrap 4, and it's having issues loading jpg and png files, specifically on the page below. The file sizes aren't that large, so I don't understand why it's not loading properly.

Anybody have ideas?

http://sparkgeo.github.io/maptiks-landing/integrations.html

Comment: It's loading fast for me. To speed up image loading, use better image compression and a CDN

Comment: Fast enough for me as well. But you'll find a lot of info on how to optimise that page **[here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsparkgeo.github.io%2Fmaptiks-landing%2Fintegrations.html)**.

Comment: That's helpful but it's still not loading properly. I think it may have to do with the code.